# Recursively Reverse an Array using Global Variables

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, global-variables

I'm not too sure how I can modify start and end when they're not in the recursive method?

For this example, I'm trying to reverse an array.

Usually end up getting StackOverflow Error for my test so far. Is there anything I should be doing instead?

```
     int start =0;
 int end =0;
 public int[] backwardArray(int[] myArray) {
     end = myArray.length-1;
     if (start < end) {
         int temp = myArray[start];
         myArray[start] = myArray[end];
         myArray[end] = temp;
         backwardArray(myArray);
         end--;
         start++;
      }
      return myArray;
 }
```

Comment: You only modify `start` and `end` *after* the recursive call that uses them...

Comment: Right, for `backwardArray()` to see new global values they'd have to be modified before the call.

Answer (score 0):

After learning that using global variables is extremely risky and not to be desired in the way I am using them here, I have found that using a helper method is more beneficial. The revision works much better:

```
public int[] backwardArray(int[] myArray) {
        return backwardArray(myArray,0,myArray.length-1);
    }
    public static int[] backwardArray(int[] myArray, int start, int end) {
        if(start<end){
               int temp = myArray[start];
               myArray[start] = myArray[end];
               myArray[end] = temp;
               return backwardArray(myArray, ++start, --end);
            }
        return myArray;   
    }
```

(Admittedly, this took me way too long realize, but) the System.out.println() would look like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        goingBackward y = new goingBackward();
        int [] x= {1,5,8,3,15,35};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y.backwardArray(x)));
        }
```